# Time zone set to Pacific while in Eastern, settings grayed out

Tags: settings

Every tutorial says go to Date and Time select Time Zone. That is all I can do as everything is grayed out, both checkbox and map. I only use eastern time zone daylight savings time. OSX=Sierra 10.12

I just bought a second hand Macbook Pro, and I'm learning to use the OS again since I haven't use a Mac in 10 years. Quite discouraged when I couldn't even adjust the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac probably is locked to the Time and Date setting because of the domain it's connected to. To change that you may need administrative access to your Mac. Do you happen to have administrative access? Is your Mac connected to a work or school domain? Was it ever on one?

Comment: As soon as it was connected to my friend's home wifi, it went to the  pacific time zone. It only has admin as a user. No work or school domain available.

Comment: Do you have access to the admin user?

Comment: Yeah! There are no other users but the admin.